# Forgot my basic math...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So a younger (college student) asked me for my help to solve a basic math question, and to my surprise, I've forgot some basic math rules, rendering me unable to answer the problem.

According to online math-generators the answer should'nt be what I'm getting.. And I am unable to follow the auto-generated steps... I hope this forum can be of help, as I actually really do like maths, (but obviously have been neglecting it)

The problem is a reduction problem, and is as follows:
$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \times\left(\frac{2}{2a}\right)+\frac{\left(\frac{2a}{6}\right)}{\left(\frac{6}{5}\right)}$

What I do is this:

---

$$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \times\left(\frac{2}{2a}\right)+\frac{\left(\frac{2a}{6}\right)}{\left(\frac{6}{5}\right)} $$

---

$$=\left(\frac{2}{6a}\right)+\frac{\left(\frac{2a}{6}\right)}{\left(\frac{6}{5}\right)} $$

---

$$=\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)+\frac{\left(\frac{1a}{3}\right)}{\left(\frac{6}{5}\right)} $$ (I fear this may be wrong?)

---

$$=\frac{\left(\frac{4}{4a}\right)}{\left(\frac{6}{5}\right)} $$

---

$$=\left(\frac{4\times5}{4\times6a}\right) $$

---

$$=\frac{20}{24a} $$

---

$$=\frac{5}{6a}$$

Comment: (2/6a)=1/3a not 1/3 (beginning of your "I fear this may be wrong" line)

Comment: But $\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{2}{2a}\neq \frac{2}{6a}$, either.

Answer (score 1):

$$(\frac{1}{2}) \times(\frac{2}{2a})+\frac{(\frac{2a}{6})}{(\frac{6}{5})}$$
$$=(\frac{1}{2a})+(\frac{2a}{6}) \times (\frac{5}{6})$$
$$=(\frac{1}{2a})+(\frac{5a}{18})$$
$$=\left(\frac{9+5a^2}{18a}\right)$$

Comment: The mistakes made point to a relearning of all the mathematical concepts you have so far cherished. start over new, with a good book and if you really like the subject you can get plenty of advise here, if you post some specific questions. Try learning from books if you dont have trained proffessors at your reach.

Answer (score 1):

You did two careless mistakes and one thing I simply don't understand.

1) 2nd line:  $\frac 1 2 \times \frac 2 {2a} = \frac 2 {4a}$ not $\frac 2 {6a}$

2) 3rd line:  "$\frac 2 {6a} = \frac 1 3$.  The $a$ has disappeared into the ether.

so you should have $(\frac{1}{2a})+\frac{(\frac{1a}{3})}{(\frac{6}{5})}$ which is reducible.

What I don't understand is how you jumped from $ (\frac{1}{3})+\frac{(\frac{1a}{3})}{(\frac{6}{5})} $(sic) to $ \frac{(\frac{4}{4a})}{(\frac{6}{5})} $.

Comment: Looks like a troll to me.

Answer (score 1):

Small mistake from step 1 to step 2. Notice that:

$$ \left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \times \left(\frac{2}{2a}\right)  = \left( \frac{1\times 2}{2\times 2a} \right) = \left(\frac{2}{4a} \right) = \left( \frac{1}{2a} \right).$$

You will then end up with 
$$ \left( \frac{1}{2a} \right) + \frac{\left(\frac{2a}{6}\right)}{\left(\frac{6}{5}\right)}.$$

You can simplify $\frac{2a}{6}$ to $\frac{a}{3}$, leaving you with

$$ \left( \frac{1}{2a} \right) + \frac{\left(\frac{a}{3}\right)}{\left(\frac{6}{5}\right)}.$$

From here, simplify $ \frac{\left(\frac{a}{3}\right)}{\left(\frac{6}{5}\right)}$ using the fact that

$$ \frac{\left(\frac{A}{B}\right)}{\left(\frac{C}{D}\right)} = \left(\frac{A}{B}\right) \times \left(\frac{D}{C}\right).$$

Once you do that, find a common denominator to add the fractions.